# nuxt.js fetching data to vuetify table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, vue-component, vuetify.js

**i am facing problem on fetching data inside vuetify table, it's not showing any data in side table.**

**MY Laravel API**

> Route::get('/businesslist',
> 'BusinessController@userlist')->name('businesslist');

**Laravel API Controller**

> ```
>  public function businesslist() {
>       $businesslist = Business::paginate(2)->toJson(JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
>       return response($businesslist);
>     }
> }
> ```

**Nuxt Code**

> ```
> <template>
>   <v-card>
>     <v-card-title>
>       Nutrition
>       <v-spacer></v-spacer>
>       <v-text-field
>         v-model="search"
>         append-icon="mdi-magnify"
>         label="Search"
>         single-line
>         hide-details
>       ></v-text-field>
>     </v-card-title>
>     <v-data-table
>       :headers="headers"
>       :items="registerlist"
>       :search="search"
>     ></v-data-table>
>   </v-card>
> </template>
>
> <script>
>   export default {
>     data () {
>       return {
>         search: '',
>         headers: [
>     
>           { text: 'SL,No', value: '' },
>           { text: 'Name', value: 'name' },
>           { text: 'Mobile  ', value: 'mobile_number' },
>           { text: 'Location  ', value: 'location' },
>           { text: 'Join Date  ', value: 'registration_date' },
>           { text: 'Renewal Date  ', value: 'registration_renewal_date' },
>         ],
>         registerlist: [
>           
>         ],
> }
>               axios.get('/Businessregisterlist')
> .then(res => this.registerlist = res.data.registerlist)
>    
>
>     },
>   }
> </script>
> ```

Comment: use function inside `.then(function(res){})` because `this` in ES6 syntax can indicate global Object.

Comment: @Mr. Perfectionist can you post your answer please for batter understand

Comment: Okay. Giving this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to call `API` within a Function like this:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       list: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
      callAPI() {
         axios.get('/', then(function(res){
            this.list = res.data.registerList;
         }))
      }
  },
   
  mounted(){
     this.callAPI(); // if you need that List on load then you can use mounted() otherwise that function will call during event.
  }
}
</script>
```

Here, inside `then()` I think it's better to use `function()`. Because if you use function then it will indicate this Object. So, we can easily access all the Object Properties (Like: data(), methods() etc.).

Comment: i implemented your code in my code there is no error but data not displaying,

Comment: Is there any data in your console?

Comment: `then(function(res){ console.log(res.data.registerlist);}))`

Comment: Perfectionist i am getting this error in console, Property or method "registerList" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Comment: This error is telling there is no `registerList`. So, `console.log(res.data)`. Is there any list in that name?

Comment: i checked console there is nothing in console

Comment: Then check your API route. If it's in an middleware you have add it before the route. Suppose, axios.get('/admin/main-url', )

Comment: in your browser check, `localhost:8000/api/Businessregisterlist` are you seeing anything? Or use POSTMAN to check your API Url

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222909/discussion-between-user12380208-and-mr-perfectionist).